# langchain emedding with huggingface can't pass the access token

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, embedding, langchain, llama-index

I am creating an index of documents with llama_index and langchain.
For the embedding I want to use https://huggingface.co/bert-base-multilingual-cased.
I had no problem creating the embedding using the following code:

```
from langchain.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from llama_index import LangchainEmbedding, ServiceContext

embed_model = LangchainEmbedding(
  HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="bert-base-multilingual-cased")
)
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(embed_model=embed_model)
```

my problem is that I don't understand how to use my HF access token when requesting the model. I want to use the access token because 1) it is suggested by the HF documentation and 2) I will probably use the HF Pro Plan in order to have an higher api rate limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use authorization tokens in `langchain.embeddings.HuggingfaceEmbeddings` but you can surely use hugging face hub if you need to use the authorization tokens.

```py
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceHubEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceHubEmbeddings(repo_id='path/to/repo', 
                           huggingfacehub_api_token='API_TOKEN')
```